# Reduce the load php cURL puts on the server

Tags: php

I'm currently using php URL to browse over 500 web pages a day with cookies.

I have to check each page to ensure that the account is still logged in and the pages are being viewed as a member, not a guest.

The script takes an hour or two to complete as it sleeps in between views.

I just want to know if there's anything I can do to reduce the load this script puts on the local server, I've made sure to clear variables at the end of each loop but is there anything I'm missing that would help?

Any new cURL settings that would help?

```
$i = 0;
$useragents = array();

foreach($urls as $url){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragents[array_rand($useragents)]);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(!$html)
        die("No HTML - Not logged in");

    if($i %10 != 0)
        sleep(rand(5,20));
    else
        sleep(rand(rand(60,180), rand(300,660)));

    $i++;

    $html = '';
}
```

Comment: `rand(rand(_,_),rand(_,_))` is the weirdest random number call I've seen in a while... Damnit, now I'm curious about the distribution of such a call!

Comment: haha I'm not quite sure why I did that looking at it now... works okay though

Comment: Would you not change `rand(60,180), rand(300,660)` to `rand(60, 660)` ? :)

Comment: Have you benchmarked to see precisely which step within the loop takes the longest?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - My guess would be a trapezoid.  Mostly flat from `180` to `300`, but slopes on either side.

Comment: @Silver89 - It's not entirely clear what you mean by "server".  Do you mean on the side where the cURL script is running or the side that cURL gets the data from?

Comment: I mean the amount of processing and memory used on the server that is running the script. I'm trying to prevent the memory from increasing on each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse your curl handle instead of creating a new one for each connection.

Clearing `$html` at the end of each iteration won't reduce memory usage and just adds an extra operation because it already gets reset in the next iteration.

```
$i = 0;
$useragents = array();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/cookies.txt');

foreach($urls as $url){

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragents[array_rand($useragents)]);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$html)
        die("No HTML - Not logged in");

    if($i++ % 10 != 0)
        sleep(rand(5,20));
    else
        sleep(rand(rand(60,180), rand(300,660)));  
}

curl_close($ch);
```